# ReactJS.NET Ajax API path mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, url-routing, reactjs.net

This is my first time using ReactJS.NET so please excuse me if this is a stupid question. I am struggling to find a solution for a declarative approach to path mapping in my ASP.NET ReactJS application.

A pet peeve of mine is, say I have an API declared in an ASP.NET MVC controller like this:

```
public class FooBarController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Foo(int bar)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            bar = bar
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
}
```

and now I want to use it in my ReactJS JSX file doing something like this:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    var bar = 10;
    axios.get('/FooBar/Foo/' + bar).then(response => {
        //console.log(response.bar) == 10;
    });
}
```

but I don't want to use a magic string like "'/FooBar/' + bar" instead I want some sort of declarative way of writing my API routes. So basically something like this:

```
axios.get(MyServices.FooBar.Foo).then(response => {
    //console.log(response.bar) == 10;
});
```

but I want auto-generation of the variables in the `MyServices` class. My biggest concern is compile time checking that the route urls are correct (in other words if I change the controller or method name, I want to get a compile time error ideally)

I thought that `react-router` might be what I am looking for but it looks more like it is a state management system using urls. I have searched but can't seem to find the right term.

Obviously I understand there are a number of ways I could achieve this end result myself but I was certain that something must exist which tackles such a common problem.